# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Why I keep getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined" when I redirect to another page and  before redirect `*ngIf="pageNumber==3"` after redirect `*ngIf="pageNumber==2"`?

this is my html file

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input #employeeNameInput="matInput" (focus)="form.controls.employeeName.focused = true" matInput formControlName="employeeName">
</mat-form-field>

<p><span [routerLink]="['/prasymas-atleisti-is-darbo', 2]" class="top-space"
         [innerHTML]="form.controls.employeeName.value" (click)="setFocus(employeeNameInput)"
         [ngClass]="{'focused': form.controls.employeeName.focused == true }"
         (clickElsewhere)="clickOff('employeeName')" [typeInput]="employeeNameInput"></span>
</p>
```

this is my ts file

```
@ViewChild('employeeNameInput') employeeNameInput: MatFormField

setFocus(input: MatInput) {
    input.focus();
}
```

the problem is when `*ngIf="pageNumber==3"` the element is hidden, but when `*ngIf="pageNumber==2"` element reapears and is not hidden, how to make that work with `*ngIf`?

Comment: Can you share Stackblitz demo?

Answer (score -1):

From the limited code example you provided above i guess the following if your problem. But would need more to confirm.

@Viewchild is targeting your reference in the DOM. If you use *ngIf to hide the part containing the component you are targeting in your ViewChild you can't get to it!

This is because *ngIf actively removes the element from the DOM it doesn't simply hide it. You could use `[hidden]` to avoid this.

`[hidden]='pageNumber !==2'` - for example

Comment: the problem is when *ngIf="pageNumber==3" the element is hidden, but when *ngIf="pageNumber==2" element reapears and is not hidden, how to make that work with `*ngIf`?

Comment: Try to wrap your input.focus(); into setTimeout(() => {}, 0) to make sure that this operation will be last.